# Interactive messages in botkit

Tags: ibm-watson, slack, slack-api, botkit

Im currently hosting the Slackbot on IBM cloud. Everything works fine until I want to add Interactive messages.

This is a part of the documentation

*In order to use interactive messages, your bot will have to be registered as a Slack application, and will have to use the Slack button authentication system. To receive callbacks, register a callback url as part of applications configuration. Botkit's built in support for the Slack Button system supports interactive message callbacks at the url https://_your_server_/slack/receive Note that Slack requires this url to be secured with https.*

So what I understod is the BOTKIT creates an Request URL I can use.
in this case https://_my_ibm_cloud_url_/slack/receive

But of course this does not work, otherwise I wouldn't be here :)

Does anybody have an idea?

This is how it's setup at the moment.

**server.js**

```
    require('dotenv').load();

    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var verify = require('./security');
    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json({
      verify: verify
    }));

    var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    app.set('port', port);

    require('./app')(app);

    // Listen on the specified port
    app.listen(port, function() {
      console.log('Client server listening on port ' + port);
    });
```

**app.js**

```
require('dotenv').load();

var middleware = require('botkit-middleware-watson')({
  iam_apikey: process.env.ASSISTANT_IAM_APIKEY,
  workspace_id: process.env.WORKSPACE_ID,
  url: process.env.ASSISTANT_URL || 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api',
  version: '2018-07-10'  
});


module.exports = function(app) {
  if (process.env.USE_SLACK) {
    console.log('test')
    var Slack = require('./bot-slack');
    Slack.controller.middleware.receive.use(middleware.receive);
    Slack.bot.startRTM();
    console.log('Slack bot is live');
  }
```

**bot-slack.js**

```
var Botkit = require('botkit');

var controller = Botkit.slackbot();


controller.configureSlackApp({
  clientId: process.env.SLACK_CLIENTID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
});

var bot = controller.spawn({
  token: process.env.SLACK_TOKEN

});

controller.hears(['.*'], ['direct_message', 'direct_mention', 'mention'], function(bot, message) {

bot.replies....

});

module.exports.controller = controller;
module.exports.bot = bot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've called the configureIncomingWebhook method to create the actual webhook endpoint.  See the docs below:

https://botkit.ai/docs/readme-slack.html#botconfigureincomingwebhook

Comment: Additionally, you probably want to use the EventsAPI instead of the RTM.

Comment: just the problem I had. Thanks!